# HDRP Decals, how to fix streching decals

Tags: unity

[image]

Is there a quick way to fix strenched decals when they don't quite perpend. to the normals in it's entirety?

What I do now is to get the normal of the surface and rotate decal accordingly, but with extreme angled corners it gets streched as a result.

Comment: This is often solved by testing the normal buffer inside the shader, and fading the decal as the normal approaches perpendicular to the decal direction. Are you using a custom shader for this, or one that's built-in or sourced from elsewhere?

Comment: I'm using HDRP Decal shader. I also have my own shader using HDRP Decal node as seen on: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/181974/shader-graph-hdrp-decal-projector